# Remover paginação do Demoiselle

Tags: java, jsf, demoiselle

Estou utilizando o Demoiselle e seu recurso de paginação, mas, quando eu preciso utilizar todos os objetos listados, ou seja, utilizar o retorno completo, ele não deixa, ele mantem a paginação.

Minha paginação:

```
@Override
public LazyDataModel<NotaFiscal> getDataModel() {
    if (dataModel == null) {
        dataModel = new LazyDataModel<NotaFiscal>() {

            @Override
            public List<NotaFiscal> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
                Pagination pagination = getPagination();
                pagination.setPageSize(pageSize);
                pagination.setFirstResult(first);

                List<NotaFiscal> itemsList = handleResultList();

                dataModel.setRowCount(pagination.getTotalResults());

                return itemsList;
            }
        };
    }
    return dataModel;
}
```

Momento em que eu preciso utilizar o resultado completo, e ele acaba pegando só o que está na primeira página:

```
public void downloadAllPDFs() {
    List<NotaFiscal> lista = handleResultList();
    if (lista == null || lista.isEmpty()) {
        //TODO - colocar mensagem
        return;
    }
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    for (NotaFiscal nf : lista) {
        try {
            NotaFiscal nota = this.notaFiscalBC.load(nf.getId());
            NotaFiscalTO notaTO = NotaFiscalToTO.geraNotaFiscalTO(nota);
            extraiPDF(files, notaTO);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            CriareLog.log(ex);
            getMessageContext().add(getResourceBundle().getString("msg.download.erro"), SeverityType.ERROR);
            return;
        }
    }
    preparaDownloadPDF(files);
}
```

Gostaria de saber se há uma maneira de remover a paginação para utilizar todo o resultado obtido?

Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Na linha:

```
List<NotaFiscal> lista = handleResultList();
```

Use:

```
List<NotaFiscal> lista = getResultList();
```

Comment: Ola. Tentei isso e não funcionou. Eu consegui quebrar o galho de outra forma mas não sei se está totalmente certo. basicamente fiz isso: 
        int total = getPagination().getTotalResults();
        int tamanhoPagina = getPagination().getPageSize();
        int firstPagina = getPagination().getFirstResult();
        int curretPage = getPagination().getCurrentPage();
        getPagination().setPageSize(total);
        getPagination().setFirstResult(0);
        getPagination().setCurrentPage(0);
        
        List<NotaFiscal> lista = handleResultList();

Comment: Não vejo problemas. Mas da forma que comentei deveria funcionar também. Qual é a versão que está usando?

Comment: Estou usando a 2.5.0